# Count the same data in nested array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, arraylist, discord

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of users with a specific ID in an array of users.
the array of users is stored in a dictionary as a value of the key "data"
The code outputs 1 instead of the expected 5.
Code:

```js
    var dlsapi = {
        url: 'https://api.discordlist.space/v2/bots/814580247973986314/upvotes',
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', authorization: process.env.DLS}
    };
    const discordlistspace = await axios.request(dlsapi);
    try {
    let dlscount = 0;
    discordlistspace.forEach(item => {
        if (item.data[0].user.id === "221838936866029568") {
            dlscount++;
        }
    });
    console.log(dlscount); 
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
```

This is the JSON(array) output from the API request in the code (the api request works fine):

```json
{
    "page": 1,
    "count": 5,
    "countPerPage": 16,
    "pageCount": 1,
    "sortBy": "timestamp",
    "sortDirection": "descending",
    "data": [{
        "user": {
            "username": "Mashwishi",
            "discriminator": "0001",
            "avatar": "a_42fd57bfe236a51d71dfde5e113143bb",
            "shortDescription": "",
            "banned": null,
            "admin": false,
            "donator": false,
            "createdAt": 1625175650578,
            "updatedAt": 1628435735580,
            "id": "221838936866029568"
        },
        "timestamp": 1628505406447,
        "id": "aef767acc68303735326b2b99a0750c704d5e64a206282bd37b94a9682aa3027"
    }, {
        "user": {
            "username": "Mashwishi",
            "discriminator": "0001",
            "avatar": "a_42fd57bfe236a51d71dfde5e113143bb",
            "shortDescription": "",
            "banned": null,
            "admin": false,
            "donator": false,
            "createdAt": 1625175650578,
            "updatedAt": 1628435735580,
            "id": "221838936866029568"
        },
        "timestamp": 1628393803968,
        "id": "3a96b21c7469db31eeb86d2371cb0d63fc5404e79afb09a738224ebcaf8aaba4"
    }, {
        "user": {
            "username": "Mashwishi",
            "discriminator": "0001",
            "avatar": "a_42fd57bfe236a51d71dfde5e113143bb",
            "shortDescription": "",
            "banned": null,
            "admin": false,
            "donator": false,
            "createdAt": 1625175650578,
            "updatedAt": 1628435735580,
            "id": "221838936866029568"
        },
        "timestamp": 1628176604500,
        "id": "36721763e54280554765bcd614a1e32945ff6f269fb3df3c7e3f8a4be921bcf8"
    }, {
        "user": {
            "username": "Mashwishi",
            "discriminator": "0001",
            "avatar": "a_42fd57bfe236a51d71dfde5e113143bb",
            "shortDescription": "",
            "banned": null,
            "admin": false,
            "donator": false,
            "createdAt": 1625175650578,
            "updatedAt": 1628435735580,
            "id": "221838936866029568"
        },
        "timestamp": 1628096627173,
        "id": "e4a7112bd50b4e1f097e792ae29a1b28ca516a11e4a0c041a88015401ac6a439"
    }, {
        "user": {
            "username": "Mashwishi",
            "discriminator": "0001",
            "avatar": "a_42fd57bfe236a51d71dfde5e113143bb",
            "shortDescription": "",
            "banned": null,
            "admin": false,
            "donator": false,
            "createdAt": 1625175650578,
            "updatedAt": 1628435735580,
            "id": "221838936866029568"
        },
        "timestamp": 1628018492326,
        "id": "160ba20531ca87e43730fa3a671914bd08b0c6c5486a8604f6401279d88803b8"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looping on the wrong object. you want to check the id for each user in the data list.
maybe try something like this

```js
    var dlsapi = {
        url: 'https://api.discordlist.space/v2/bots/814580247973986314/upvotes',
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', authorization: process.env.DLS}
    };
    try {
        let dlscount = 0;
        discordlistspace.data.data.forEach(item => {
            if (item.user.id === "221838936866029568") {
                dlscount++;
            }
        });
        console.log(dlscount); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
```

EDIT: if you want a shorter code you can replace the entire try block like that:

```js
    var dlsapi = {
        url: 'https://api.discordlist.space/v2/bots/814580247973986314/upvotes',
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', authorization: process.env.DLS}
    };
    try {
        let dlscount = discordListspace.data.data.filter(item => item.user.id == "221838936866029568").length;
        console.log(dlscount); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
```

filter is a method for arrays that filters (as the name suggests) the array: keeps only the elements that satisfy a specific condition
so you can filter the array to contain only users with the id, and then check the results length

Comment: Thank you so much, thank you for explaining my mistakes too

Comment: no problem! btw, you can replace the === comparator with the more popular ==

Comment: currently encountering (node:5296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: dlscount is not defined

Comment: and TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined after changing to ==

Comment: can you update the question with the new code and error so I can have some context?

Comment: both, the code you send and the short code

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" happens probably because the "[0]" is not needed

Comment: I also tried removing that based on the note you send it it throw: TypeError: discordlistspace.data.filter is not a function

Comment: on the first code without [0] thows: TypeError: discordlistspace.data.forEach is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235792/discussion-between-atanay-and-mashwishi).

Comment: Worked at: `discordlistspace.data.data.filter(item => item.user.id == "221838936866029568").length;` thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Plese try this.

```
JsonObj.data.forEach(item => {
if (item.user.id === '221838936866029568') dlscount++;});
```

yields 5